# How to delete first few odd numbers from array in php until the next number is even?

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to write a PHP code which delete the first few odd numbers until the next number is even with using loop. 
Printing the Fibonacci series works, but it does not delete first few odd numbers.
My Fibonacci numbers: `1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377`
And the result what I would like to print out: `2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377`
My code:

```
<?php

$fibarray = array(1, 1);
$fibarray[2] = $fibarray[0] + $fibarray[1];

for ( $i=2; $i<=13; ++$i ) {
 $fibarray[$i] = $fibarray[$i-1] + $fibarray[$i-2];
} 

foreach ($fibarray as $final) {
    for ($i=0; $i<=15; $i++) {
        if ($fibarray[$i]%2 != 0) {
            unset($fibarray[$final]);
        }
    }
    echo $final.' ';
}
?>
```

Can you help me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can iterate the array to find first even num. here is the [demo](https://eval.in/682719).

```
$fibarray = array(1, 1);
$fibarray[2] = $fibarray[0] + $fibarray[1];

for ( $i=2; $i<=13; ++$i ) {
 $fibarray[$i] = $fibarray[$i-1] + $fibarray[$i-2];
 }

  //$array = array(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377);
  $array = $fibarray;
  $index = 0; $length = count($array);
  for(; $index < $length; $index++)
  {
   if( ($array[$index] & 1) == 0)
    break;
  }
  $resultArray = array_slice($array, $index);
  echo implode(' ', $resultArray )."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

use array_filter() http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php with a callback that does the %2 modulus if check infact the first example on that page shows you exactly to do what you want to do

```
<?php
function odd($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is odd
    return($var & 1);
}

function even($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is even
    return(!($var & 1));
}

$array1 = array("a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5);
$array2 = array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

echo "Odd :\n";
print_r(array_filter($array1, "odd"));
echo "Even:\n";
print_r(array_filter($array2, "even"));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not what I would like to do. I want to say the program that "Check the first value in array, if it is odd number then delete it. Check the second value, if it is odd too delete it. Check the third value, it is already even, so stop the program." I do not want to delete all odd numbers in array.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach()` iterates the array and exposes the `$key => $value` pair.  So use the key to `unset()` the array element if it is odd and `break` out of the loop if it is even:

```
foreach ($fibarray as $key => $value) {
    if ($value % 2 != 0) {
        unset($fibarray[$key]);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```